# React Native - Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

New to RN and iOS development.

I'm trying to have XCode automatically manage signing and such, but apparently I need a physical device in order to access a provisioning profile?

I don't have an iPhone or iPad, but I'm developing an iPhone/iPad app from my Macbook.

Can someone explain what I'm not understanding here?

Comment: You can create provisioning profiles from your developer account without connecting an actual device. But you need to be enrolled in iOS developer program.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need an actual device. You just need to make sure you have your developer certificates downloaded from developer.apple.com. After that in the general tab just select your team from the signing menu. Then Xcode will auto create a provisioning file.